# Transaction-independent database-hosted logging for MySQL stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am a beginner in MySQL, looking for expert advise ...

I need to create 4 logging stored procedures:

1. OPEN_LOG(code, comment)
2. CLOSE_LOG(result)
3. BEGIN_ACTION(action, comment)
4. END_ACTION(result)

to use them in my stored procedures like this:

`START TRANSACTION;
    CALL open_log('ETL_ABC', 'Running ETL process ABC');
      CALL begin_action('Refreshing Dimensions', 'CUSTOMERS, PRODUCTS, STORES');
      MERGE INTO customers ...;
      MERGE INTO products ...;
      MERGE INTO stores' ...;
      CALL end_action('Done');
      CALL begin_action('Loading new SALES data', 'For 01-APR-2018');
      INSERT INTO sales ...;
      CALL end_action('... rows added');
    CALL close_log('Successfully completed');
    COMMIT;`

The OPEN_LOG procedure should insert 1 row into the PROCESS_LOGS table.
The CLOSE_LOG procedure should update that row with RESULT and END_DATE_TIME values. The BEGIN_ACTION procedure should insert 1 row into the LOG_DATA table. The END_ACTION procedure should insert yet another row into the same LOG_DATA table. All these inserts and updates should be independent from the main transaction.

There may be many ETL processes running simultaneously in the system and using this logging mechanism. At the same time, support staff can manually query these logging tables to see what is running and at what stage the processes are.

In Oracle, I was able to achieve this by declaring my logging procedures with PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION.

In MySQL/MariaDB, I believe my only option is using MyISAM storage engine for the logging tables. My concern is concurrency. I estimate that I may need to allow up to 100 log writes per second and up to 10 queries per minute. The queries should be quick because both log tables will properly indexed.

Please, give me your opinion/alternatives.

Comment: unless staffs are using the same connection, they won't be able to see what's happening until the current transaction get commited /rolled back. Logs must come out of transaction so one can view progress from outside.

Comment: @krish KM: not true. I checked: the changes in MyISAM tables are immediately visible for other sessions/connections - even before the transaction is committed.

Comment: Think about it, if so, what's the point of using transactions anyway? Besides MyISAM doesn't really support transactions. They all auto committed, which is why it's true what you say.

Comment: I improved the original design a little by giving my procedures a choice to write either into MyISAM tables or into MEMORY tables with possibility to save the MEMORY-based data into MyISAM tables in case of an exception - for debugging purposes. I implemented this solution using MariaDB mode_sql=ORACLE syntax. See here: [link](https://github.com/OlegKhaykin/OK_Lib/tree/master/MariaDB_in_ORACLE_mode/2.XL). I tested it by running 100 parallel sessions. It looks like contention is not a problem, the performance is great even on my heavily loaded DELL PowerEdge  T110 server with 8 CPs and 32GB RAM

Comment: I encountered terrible contention problems when inserting into temporary tables in a cyclical manner from multiple sessions. Here is the scenario: every session produces a lot of log data, but only the latest ~100 entries are useful for debugging when the program errors-out because of an unexpected error. So, instead of inserting all this log data into a MyISAM log table, I am inserting it into a temporary table located in memory. When it reaches 100 rows, I begin updating rows, starting with the 1st one. Also, I tried truncating the table and populating it again. It did not help.

Comment: Please, disregard my previous post. The delays were not caused by contention. I simply put too much load on my server. Everything works well. I re-implemented my logging solution using plain MySQL syntax rather than MariaDB with Oracle. Please, see the code [here]( https://github.com/OlegKhaykin/OK_Lib/tree/master/MySQL/XL).